# SD of a bernoulli trial?

Tags: probability-distributions

Why nothing is mentioned about the standard deviation  of a Bernoulli trial ?

Does it even make sense if I try to visualize it ?

Comment: With usual terms ($p(1)=p,\;p(0)=1-p$) then $\sigma =\sqrt {p(1-p)}$.  This comes up a lot!  In particular it comes up if you have many trials and would like to approximate with a normal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why nothing is mentioned about the standard deviation of a Bernoulli trial ?

*Where?* Standard textbooks will have some mention regarding the variance, at a minimum. *Regardless*, you (I) can derive it yourself (myself).

If $X$ is a Bernoulli trial with chance $p$,
then
$$E[X] =\sum_{k = 0}^1 kP(X = k) = 0\cdot(1-p)+1\cdot p = p,$$
and 
$$E[X^2] = \sum_{k = 0}^1 k^2P(X=  k) = 0^2\cdot(1-p)+1^2\cdot p =  p.$$

Hence
$$\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2]-\{E[X]\}^2 = p-p^2 = p(1-p)$$
and so
$$\text{SD}(X) = \sqrt{p(1-p)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

If $p$ is the probability of success, then the variance of a Bernoulli random variable is $p(1-p)$, hence the standard deviation is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

Comment: yes, but given for e.g the set [10,612,642,3,-64] I can easily see a standard deviation if I were to draw the bell curve but if I am given many 1(success) or 0(failure) of an experiment then it's not clear how spread apart really they are.

Comment: Well that's a different random variable. If $X$ counts the number of successes in $n$ trials, then the standard deviation of $X$ is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.